# Associative array turned into where OR clause in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, associative-array

using CI I'm trying to set up query with three parameters: user_id, content_type and content_id in which content_id is array of IDs.

So I need to get up with something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM content WHERE user_id = 2 AND content_type = file AND (content_id = 4 OR content_id = 5 OR content_id = 7 ...).
```

1. question: is this right query to get all the content_ids?
2. does CI have any function where I can say

   ```
       $this->db->select('name');
       $this->db->from('content');
       $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
       $this->db->where('content_ids', $content_ids);
       $this->db->where('content_type', $content_type);
   ```

   just so that middle where clause is actually where with nested ORs in between and its filled with associative array ($content_ids)?

Thank you for answers.

EDIT: I have found a solution: where_in command does exactly what I need.

Comment: OK, I have just found out about where_in clause from CI. Is that the right direction?

Comment: Yep thats right way you were proceeding

Comment: For using `where_or` OP need to use `loop` instead `where_in` will do it simply without loop @saty

Comment: yaa i know that's y i delete my comment.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you should post your solution as an answer, just in case anyone else has a similar question =]

Comment: I've posted my answer @Novocaine. _For the sake of completeness_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **IN** clause to replace many **OR** conditions

So your query within Active Records looks like

```
$content_ids = array(4,5,7);
$where = array('user_id' => $user_id,'content_type' => $content_type);
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('content');
$this->db->where($where);//created array of where clause
$this->db->where_in('content_type', $content_ids);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Are you sure u have to implode content_ids? On manual pages there is a pure array used..

Comment: Yep you can directly use the array within implode thanks for pointing out that @SubjectX. Even I've updated my answer too